# Network becomes unavailable after suspend or network change

Tags: networking, network-manager, suspend

```
$ lsb_release -a 
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
```

Whenever I suspend my machine, or connect via WiFi and then plug in an ethernet cable, I am unable to access the internet.

I have tried restarting various services (`sudo service networking restart`, `sudo service network-manager restart`) to no avail.

The only solution is to reboot the machine, which is very inconvenient.

Output from `dmesg -T`:

```
[Wed May 10 12:30:09 2017] usb 1-1: new full-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[Wed May 10 12:30:09 2017] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=046d, idProduct=c52f
[Wed May 10 12:30:09 2017] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[Wed May 10 12:30:09 2017] usb 1-1: Product: USB Receiver
[Wed May 10 12:30:09 2017] usb 1-1: Manufacturer: Logitech
[Wed May 10 12:30:09 2017] hidraw: raw HID events driver (C) Jiri Kosina
[Wed May 10 12:30:09 2017] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
[Wed May 10 12:30:09 2017] usbhid: USB HID core driver
[Wed May 10 12:30:09 2017] input: Logitech USB Receiver as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0/0003:046D:C52F.0001/input/input17
[Wed May 10 12:30:09 2017] hid-generic 0003:046D:C52F.0001: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [Logitech USB Receiver] on usb-0000:00:14.0-1/input0
[Wed May 10 12:30:09 2017] input: Logitech USB Receiver as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.1/0003:046D:C52F.0002/input/input18
[Wed May 10 12:30:09 2017] hid-generic 0003:046D:C52F.0002: input,hiddev0,hidraw1: USB HID v1.11 Device [Logitech USB Receiver] on usb-0000:00:14.0-1/input1
[Wed May 10 12:30:10 2017] usb 1-3: new low-speed USB device number 6 using xhci_hcd
[Wed May 10 12:30:10 2017] usb 1-3: New USB device found, idVendor=046d, idProduct=c31c
[Wed May 10 12:30:10 2017] usb 1-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[Wed May 10 12:30:10 2017] usb 1-3: Product: USB Keyboard
[Wed May 10 12:30:10 2017] usb 1-3: Manufacturer: Logitech
[Wed May 10 12:30:10 2017] usb 1-3: ep 0x81 - rounding interval to 64 microframes, ep desc says 80 microframes
[Wed May 10 12:30:10 2017] usb 1-3: ep 0x82 - rounding interval to 1024 microframes, ep desc says 2040 microframes
[Wed May 10 12:30:10 2017] input: Logitech USB Keyboard as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3/1-3:1.0/0003:046D:C31C.0003/input/input19
[Wed May 10 12:30:10 2017] hid-generic 0003:046D:C31C.0003: input,hidraw2: USB HID v1.10 Keyboard [Logitech USB Keyboard] on usb-0000:00:14.0-3/input0
[Wed May 10 12:30:10 2017] input: Logitech USB Keyboard as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3/1-3:1.1/0003:046D:C31C.0004/input/input20
[Wed May 10 12:30:11 2017] hid-generic 0003:046D:C31C.0004: input,hidraw3: USB HID v1.10 Device [Logitech USB Keyboard] on usb-0000:00:14.0-3/input1
[Wed May 10 12:30:14 2017] ------------[ cut here ]------------
[Wed May 10 12:30:14 2017] WARNING: CPU: 1 PID: 1525 at /build/linux-Hlembm/linux-4.4.0/ubuntu/i915/intel_pm.c:3675 skl_update_other_pipe_wm+0x16c/0x180 [i915_bpo]()
[Wed May 10 12:30:14 2017] WARN_ON(!wm_changed)
[Wed May 10 12:30:14 2017] Modules linked in:
[Wed May 10 12:30:14 2017]  hid_generic usbhid hid nf_conntrack_netlink nfnetlink xfrm_user xfrm_algo xt_addrtype br_netfilter aufs pci_stub vboxpci(OE) vboxnetadp(OE) vboxnetflt(OE) vboxdrv(OE) ctr ccm xt_CHECKSUM iptable_mangle ipt_MASQUERADE nf_nat_masquerade_ipv4 iptable_nat nf_nat_ipv4 nf_nat nf_conntrack_ipv4 nf_defrag_ipv4 xt_conntrack nf_conntrack ipt_REJECT nf_reject_ipv4 xt_tcpudp bridge stp llc ebtable_filter ebtables ip6table_filter ip6_tables iptable_filter ip_tables x_tables bnep binfmt_misc arc4 iwlmvm mac80211 snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic snd_soc_skl snd_soc_skl_ipc snd_hda_ext_core snd_soc_sst_ipc snd_soc_sst_dsp snd_soc_core uvcvideo iwlwifi snd_compress ac97_bus snd_pcm_dmaengine dw_dmac_core videobuf2_vmalloc videobuf2_memops snd_hda_intel videobuf2_v4l2 snd_hda_codec
[Wed May 10 12:30:14 2017]  cfg80211 videobuf2_core snd_hda_core v4l2_common btusb btrtl snd_hwdep btbcm videodev btintel snd_pcm media bluetooth rtsx_pci_ms memstick intel_rapl shpchp x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp input_leds joydev serio_raw thinkpad_acpi mei_me mei nvram snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event snd_rawmidi snd_seq snd_seq_device snd_timer snd soundcore mac_hid tpm_crb kvm_intel kvm irqbypass parport_pc ppdev lp parport autofs4 drbg ansi_cprng algif_skcipher af_alg dm_crypt rtsx_pci_sdmmc crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel aesni_intel aes_x86_64 lrw i915_bpo gf128mul glue_helper ablk_helper cryptd intel_ips i2c_algo_bit e1000e drm_kms_helper psmouse syscopyarea sysfillrect sysimgblt ptp fb_sys_fops pps_core drm ahci rtsx_pci libahci wmi video fjes
[Wed May 10 12:30:14 2017] CPU: 1 PID: 1525 Comm: Xorg Tainted: G           OE   4.4.0-75-generic #96-Ubuntu
[Wed May 10 12:30:14 2017] Hardware name: LENOVO 20FH000HZA/20FH000HZA, BIOS N1KET16W (1.03 ) 01/20/2016
[Wed May 10 12:30:14 2017]  0000000000000286 00000000e3e77475 ffff880404b47920 ffffffff813f8493
[Wed May 10 12:30:14 2017]  ffff880404b47968 ffffffffc02c1b58 ffff880404b47958 ffffffff81081302
[Wed May 10 12:30:14 2017]  ffff88040b4da000 ffff8804048ca148 ffff88040b4db000 ffff880405ac4b78
[Wed May 10 12:30:14 2017] Call Trace:
[Wed May 10 12:30:14 2017]  [<ffffffff813f8493>] dump_stack+0x63/0x90
[Wed May 10 12:30:14 2017]  [<ffffffff81081302>] warn_slowpath_common+0x82/0xc0
[Wed May 10 12:30:14 2017]  [<ffffffff8108139c>] warn_slowpath_fmt+0x5c/0x80
[Wed May 10 12:30:14 2017]  [<ffffffffc01e2fec>] skl_update_other_pipe_wm+0x16c/0x180 [i915_bpo]
[Wed May 10 12:30:14 2017]  [<ffffffffc01e3185>] skl_update_wm+0x185/0x610 [i915_bpo]
[Wed May 10 12:30:14 2017]  [<ffffffffc027442f>] ? intel_ddi_enable_transcoder_func+0x17f/0x260 [i915_bpo]
[Wed May 10 12:30:14 2017]  [<ffffffffc01e6f0e>] intel_update_watermarks+0x1e/0x30 [i915_bpo]
[Wed May 10 12:30:14 2017]  [<ffffffffc0256701>] haswell_crtc_enable+0x761/0x8e0 [i915_bpo]
[Wed May 10 12:30:14 2017]  [<ffffffffc0252606>] intel_atomic_commit+0x5d6/0x14a0 [i915_bpo]
[Wed May 10 12:30:14 2017]  [<ffffffffc0082bfe>] ? drm_atomic_check_only+0x18e/0x590 [drm]
[Wed May 10 12:30:14 2017]  [<ffffffffc0083037>] drm_atomic_commit+0x37/0x60 [drm]
[Wed May 10 12:30:14 2017]  [<ffffffffc0137dc6>] drm_atomic_helper_set_config+0x76/0xb0 [drm_kms_helper]
[Wed May 10 12:30:14 2017]  [<ffffffffc0071e12>] drm_mode_set_config_internal+0x62/0x100 [drm]
[Wed May 10 12:30:14 2017]  [<ffffffffc007646c>] drm_mode_setcrtc+0x3cc/0x4f0 [drm]
[Wed May 10 12:30:14 2017]  [<ffffffffc0067722>] drm_ioctl+0x152/0x540 [drm]
[Wed May 10 12:30:14 2017]  [<ffffffffc00760a0>] ? drm_mode_setplane+0x1b0/0x1b0 [drm]
[Wed May 10 12:30:14 2017]  [<ffffffff81222c6f>] do_vfs_ioctl+0x29f/0x490
[Wed May 10 12:30:14 2017]  [<ffffffff8108e5a1>] ? __set_task_blocked+0x41/0xa0
[Wed May 10 12:30:14 2017]  [<ffffffff81090f36>] ? __set_current_blocked+0x36/0x60
[Wed May 10 12:30:14 2017]  [<ffffffff81222ed9>] SyS_ioctl+0x79/0x90
[Wed May 10 12:30:14 2017]  [<ffffffff810911ee>] ? SyS_rt_sigprocmask+0x8e/0xc0
[Wed May 10 12:30:14 2017]  [<ffffffff8183b972>] entry_SYSCALL_64_fastpath+0x16/0x71
[Wed May 10 12:30:14 2017] ---[ end trace cd5e485c094f6974 ]---
[Wed May 10 12:30:17 2017] snd_hda_codec_hdmi hdaudioC0D2: HDMI: ELD buf size is 0, force 128
[Wed May 10 12:30:17 2017] snd_hda_codec_hdmi hdaudioC0D2: HDMI: invalid ELD data byte 0
[Wed May 10 12:30:21 2017] thinkpad_acpi: EC reports that Thermal Table has changed
[Wed May 10 12:30:24 2017] e1000e: enp0s31f6 NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: Rx/Tx
[Wed May 10 12:30:24 2017] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): enp0s31f6: link becomes ready
[Wed May 10 12:30:33 2017] i915_bpo 0000:00:02.0: BAR 6: [??? 0x00000000 flags 0x2] has bogus alignment
[Wed May 10 12:30:35 2017] snd_hda_codec_hdmi hdaudioC0D2: HDMI: ELD buf size is 0, force 128
[Wed May 10 12:30:35 2017] snd_hda_codec_hdmi hdaudioC0D2: HDMI: invalid ELD data byte 0
[Wed May 10 12:31:32 2017] wlp4s0: authenticate with fe:9f:db:8b:0a:8e
[Wed May 10 12:31:32 2017] wlp4s0: send auth to fe:9f:db:8b:0a:8e (try 1/3)
[Wed May 10 12:31:32 2017] wlp4s0: authenticated
[Wed May 10 12:31:32 2017] wlp4s0: associate with fe:9f:db:8b:0a:8e (try 1/3)
[Wed May 10 12:31:32 2017] wlp4s0: RX AssocResp from fe:9f:db:8b:0a:8e (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=5)
[Wed May 10 12:31:32 2017] wlp4s0: associated
```

Comment: You can try an alternate network manager but people say its gui is ugly haha https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WICD

Comment: Also I see you say you plug in an Ethernet after connecting to a wifi connection . Can I see an ifconfig when the problem if happening to see if both your wireless and Ethernet have local ips at same time ? also can i see a traceroute sudo apt-get install traceroute EX: traceroute google.com minus personal ip from info plz